# Visual Studio 2012 shell keeps breaking- SSIS in particular

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual Studio 2012 shell installed just for SQL Server Data tools so I can do SSIS and SSAS projects. I used it for several days and one afternoon, it just wouldn't work- got a popup saying "Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working" and it had these long error messages in any windows relating to SSIS, like the SSIS toolbox and Variables window. I ran it in safe mode and no longer got the popup message, but still saw the SSIS errors and SSIS projects would not load (in Solution Explorer they were empty and say "incompatible"). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling VS and installed CU5 and CU15 (cumulative updates) for SQL Server and even started uninstalling SQL Server (that got complicated, it never seemed to really remove everything), but ran out of luck and reformatted my computer. After doing that, I installed SQL Server (Developer edition) and VS and things worked great for a couple days until I installed Windows Updates last night. This morning, Visual Studio was back showing the errors again. This is so frustrating!! I tried uninstalling all updates that I saw that ran the last couple days.

Errors that appear in SSIS Toolbox (or Variables window, etc):

An exception was encountered while constructing the content of this frame.  This information is also logged in "C\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml". Exception details: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension' threw an exception.--->

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.--->

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SQLServer.Dts.Design, Version=11.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Common.ImageSourceHelper.GetImageSourceFromResource(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, Size size) at

Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Designer.Common.ImageSourceHelper.GetImageSourceFromResource(Assembly assembly, String resourceName, Boolean isLarge)

etc

I am unable to see the rest of the error right now, but I also saw this error frequently before I reformatted my computer: "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Design.SharedIcons' threw an exception. I think I saw this after I ran VS in Safe Mode, and then started it again, although I haven't seen it this time around.

Comment: In all possibility, the SSDT version that you are trying to run is not compatible with the VS you have. Also, make sure the .NET framework is appropriate. I had similar issues when I installed VS 2012 and tried to run the SSDT on 2010 shell. It just craps out.

Comment: I have .net 4.5. I downloaded it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843.  Maybe it's Windows 8.1 related- my coworker has just 8 and hasn't had issues.

Comment: That looks like the version even I would've got if I were you. The other thing that comes to my mind is the location of the installs. By default the new OS installations have 2 folders in the C drive (or whatever drive your OS is installed on). These are "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)". The latter being for 32 bit apps. Make sure you are installing VS and SSDT in the same directory structure. VS is complaining that it cant find the necessary DLL's that it needs to make SSDT successful.

Comment: What about virus scanners & junk like UAC? Are those turned off? How about SQL Server patches? Have you installed those?

Comment: I have done some SQL Server patches the first time around (before I reformatted). We do have McAfee anti-virus here at work, required on my laptop. I could try the patches again, I suppose. I appreciate the help, although I may put this on hold for a couple days (out of town)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this by opening up SQL Server Installation Center. I went to Maintenance and then Repair, and once that finished, VS started working again. I also want to point out that while Repair was running, I got a couple error popups and messages asking me to insert a CD or media file that I did not have. I just hit Cancel or whatever was needed to move on, so don't be deterred by that.